# Vertex coloring proof question

Tags: graph-theory

There is a graph $G$ such that if any pair of vertices is removed, then its chromatic number decrease by $2$. Show that $G$ is complete graph.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: If $G$ is not complete, there are vertices $v$ and $w$ in $G$ such that $\{v,w\}$ is not an edge of $G$. Let $G'$ be the graph that remains when $v$ and $w$ are removed. Show that restoring $v$ and $w$ adds at most one color.

Comment: @12arte12: You’re welcome.